# Show the Cauchy-Riemann equations hold but f is not differentiable

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, derivatives

> Let $$f(z)={x^{4/3} y^{5/3}+i\,x^{5/3}y^{4/3}\over x^2+y^2}\text{ if }z\neq0
> \text{, and }f(0)=0$$ 
>   Show that the Cauchy-Riemann equations hold at $z=0$ but $f$ is not differentiable at $z=0$

Here's what I've done so far:

$\quad$As noted above, there are two cases: $z=0$ and $z\neq0$. The Cauchy-Riemann equations hold at $\quad z\neq0$ because $f(x)$ is analytic everywhere except at the origin.

$\quad$Now we consider $z=0$. In this case, 
$$f_x(0,0) = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{0 + 0}{x^2+0}=0$$ 
$\quad$and
$$f_y(0,0) = \lim_{y\to 0} \frac{0 + 0}{0+y^2}=0$$

$\quad$So, we see that $\frac{\delta u}{\delta x}=0=\frac{\delta v}{\delta y}$ and $\frac{\delta u}{\delta y}=0= -\frac{\delta v}{\delta x}$. Therefore, the Cauchy-Riemann equations $\quad$hold at $z=0$.

From here, I'm a little confused about how to show that $f$ is not differentiable at $z=0$. I instinctively believe that $f$ is not continuous at $z=0$, which would imply that $f$ is not differentiable at $z=0$. However, I'm not sure how I can prove this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!!

**EDIT:**

I now see that $f$ is continuous at $z=0$, but I'm not sure how to prove that it is not differentiable.  I know I should use $\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{f(z) - f(0)}{z-0}$ to determine differentiability, and that I should get two different answers when I approach the limit from two different paths (for example: $x=0$, $y=0$, or $x=y$), but I'm not sure how to evaluate $\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{f(z) - f(0)}{z-0}$ for $x=0$, $y=0$ or $x=y$.

As before, any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If $f$ is not continuous at 0, how could it be differentiable?

Comment: @RickSanchez Very true. I guess I intuitively see that $f$ is not continuous at $z=0$, but I'm unsure how I am supposed to show or prove that $f$ is not continuous at $z=0$. I'll edit the post to reflect that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Are the limits as $x \to 0$ and $y \to 0$ the same? Because if the limit does not exist and equal the same value for EVERY direction of approach to the origin, then the limit does not exist there.

EDIT: The same argument would work with directional derivatives at the origin; if any two are not equal, then the function (considered as a function on R^2), can not be differentiable and hence whether or not the Cauchy-Riemann equations hold is insufficient.

However, do note that even if all directional derivatives exist and *are* equal, this is still not sufficient to prove the differentiability at the origin; it is only a necessary, but not a sufficient condition.

Comment: Of course! Got it. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: $f$ is continuous at $z=0$

Comment: I don't get "even if all directional derivatives exist and are equal, this is still not sufficient to prove the differentiability at the origin; it is only a necessary, but not a sufficient condition.
" and the directional derivative is $\partial_v f(z_0) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(z_0+h v)-f(z_0)}{h}$ (with $h$ real) hence you mean $\frac{\partial_v f(z_0)}{v}$ exists for every $v \ne 0$ and doesn't depend on $v$, which is equivalent to the Cauchy-Riemann equation, and is equivalent to the the complex-differentiability of $f(z)$ at $z_0$

Comment: @Dr.MV $f$ is continuous at $z=0$ because $f(0)$ is defined, correct? I'm getting a little confused.

Comment: It is continuous since $\lim_{z\to 0}f(z)=0=f(0)$.

Comment: Basically complex differentiability is equivalent to Frechet (total) differentiability plus satisfying the Cauchy-Riemann equations. The existence and equality of all directional derivatives at a point is Gateaux differentiability, which is not enough to guarantee the existence of a linear transformation ("matrix") approximating the function at the point. Thus if a function satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations but is not complex differentiable, then it must fail to be Frechet differentiable; being Gateaux differentiable is necessary but not sufficient for this to be the case.

Comment: I.e. if the total derivative exists, then all directional derivatives exist and are equal (and the linear transformation is simply the Jacobian at the point), but even if all directional derivatives exist and are equal (i.e. Gateaux differentiability - the Jacobian is well-behaved with respect to changes of coordinates via rotation) that doesn't mean that the Jacobian actually approximates the function well at that point (Frechet differentiability).