# The relationship between Cauchy-Riemann equations and differentiability

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, cauchy-riemann-equations

What is the relationship between Cauchy-Riemann equations and differentiability of a complex valued function at any point $z=z_0$? If Cauchy-Riemann equations are satisfied at $z=z_0$ then can we say that $f(z)$ is differentiable at $z=z_0$?

Comment: It is also necessary that Re(f) and Im(f) be real differentiable

Answer (score 1):

The reply is probably too late, but:

According to the theorem, that f(z) satisfies Cauchy-Riemann equation is the necessary condition for the complex function to be complex differentiable. The sufficient conditions also require all first order partial derivatives of u, v (where f(x,y)=u(x,y) + iv(x,y)) are **continuous** (at z=z_0.)

Hence, complex differentiability implies f satisfying C-R equation, but not the other way around. Here I found an counter example: [Show the Cauchy-Riemann equations hold but f is not differentiable](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1758824/829853).

Comment: But if CR holds weakly on an open set, the function is analytic.

Comment: @Deane Sorry, I may not know what does “CR holds weakly” mean, is a new concept or could you show an example?

Comment: Here’s one explanation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_solution. A book on PDEs that mentions distributions (generalized functions) will also explain this.